# Serre's Topics in Galois Theory

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, galois-theory

I am supposed to write a running notes on Hilbert Irreducibility Theorem from Serre's *Topics in Galois Theory* as part of my master's Algebra course work. But I don't have any knowledge of Algebraic Geometry, little knowledge of Commutative Algebra, and comfortable with Field Theory and Galois Theory (Serge Lang, *Algebra*).

I am clueless how to start the book, I don't even know what are the prerequisites to start the book. Please suggest me how to start with prerequisites, and please do recommend books too. (I need to submit in first week of October).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See Lang's Diophantine Geometry

Comment: Thanks Soloveichik, I saw that book.